# Error in sql to node js. Error :Packets out of order. Got: 45 Expected: 0

Tags: mysql, node.js

I get an error in SQL TO NODE JS
Is there anything I did not do well?
Is there a problem with my connection to the server (this is an amazon server)
2 Is there a problem with the rest of the code
Thanks

```
const mysql  = require('mysql');
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : "142.**.**.***",
  port     : '22',
  user     : 'db-*****',
  password : 'Yo*****'
});

 
connection.connect();
 
connection.query('SELECT * FROM wp_redirection_groups',  (error, results, fields) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
  console.log(results);
});
 
connection.end();
```

Do I need to change anything

> Error: Packets out of order. Got: 45 Expected: 0
> at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:470:15)
> at Parser.write (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:33:29)
> at Protocol.write (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
> at Socket. (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
> at Socket. (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
> at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
> --------------------
> at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
> at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
> at Connection.connect (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\משתמש\Documents\GitHub\whatsapp-bot\sql.js:9:12)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',   fatal: true }

Answer (score 0):

A connection is implicit with any query so you don't need the `connect()` function and you don't generally need the `end()` function unless you are really working at scale and have good reason to manually manage your connections. A connection will be re-used, closed, re-connected as needed.

I'd be curious to understand why you're using `PORT: 22` as this is usually dedicated to `SSH` traffic and using it would require good reason and a lot of custom configurations in many places. The default `mysql` port is `3306` so I'd just double check that you have everything configured the way you wish. Regardless of the value, it should be provided as in `int`, not a `string`

Below is a simplified snippet:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '142.**.**.***',
  port     : 22,
  user     : 'db-*****',
  password : 'Yo*****'
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM wp_redirection_groups;', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) console.log('there was an error', error);
  // connected, query complete, no errors
  console.log('the results object is:', results);
});
```

Because this `connection.query()` example exists on its own (not as a part of any defined function that might be called when needed) you should expect this query to execute one time, immediately after starting your `node` app as long as it's included in your root file or an included module.